# Google Cloud AI Platform training job: --stream-logs stalls indefinitely with no output

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-ai

I am submitting a training job with

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training [...] --stream-logs
```

The job is submitted successfully, but no logs appear on the terminal. No output after "Job [...] submitted successfully." appears, but the command doesn't terminate either.

When I go to check on the online console, I see that the job is running and producing logs (which are not showing up in the terminal where I ran the command). Even when the job completes successfully, the command still doesn't terminate.

The same happens if I first run `gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training` without `--stream-logs` and then run `gcloud ai-platform jobs stream-logs` on the new job.

Do you know any reason this could be happening, and/or any way I can fix it?

---

**EDIT:** I left the command running for a while, and about 20 min after the job had already finished and succeeded, all of a sudden all the logs appear and the command terminates. So it is working, kind of, but it takes ages before it gets synced, it seems.

Comment: I did try training a job using the example [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/docs/getting-started-keras#train_your_model_using) and experienced the same issue as yours. I created an [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/182438732) to address this issue.

Comment: Did you find a fix for the thing you mentioned in your edit? I can't find a way to get logs synced and my logs also appear only at the end of the job.

Comment: @Megastore No, in the end I just had to put up with it. It seems to be an issue with the implementation, see the comment above for an issue page created by Ricco D.

Comment: I have the same:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training test_$(uuidgen | sed s/-//g) \
  --region us-east1 \
  --package-path mystrategy \
  --module-name mystrategy \
  --staging-bucket ... \
  --runtime-version 2.4 \
  --python-version 3.7 \
  --service-account ... \
  --scale-tier BASIC_GPU \
  --stream-logs
Job [test_761bc9b0fe084e6297a29f5526f0953e] submitted successfully.
```

(and no output, or output which is lagging minutes behind)